# Brightness keys don't work on a Toshiba Satellite L655

Tags: shortcut-keys, brightness, radeon

I have a laptop toshiba satallite L655  with ATI Radeon HD 5650.
I have a problem in my super key for the brigthness.
When ever i press <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>f6</kbd> or <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd> to increase or decrease the light, nothing happens. By the way, this problem started when i installed my graphic card driver from `Ubuntu Additional Drivers` ...
please can any one help me!!!

Comment: this problem happen when i restart the computer or start it...and it dosen't happen regualry...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me : [Re: Controlling brightness on 12.04 Toshiba L650](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11966072&postcount=2) and I am on a L455D-S5976

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.